# How to trigger another model of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use angular to write a dialog,when click button,append element.

html code:

```
<div class="box" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="conCtrl">
    <button ng-click="creatDir()">click me!</button>
</div>
```

dialogApp code:

```
angular.module('dialogApp', []).
    factory('dialogFactory', ["$document","$interpolate",function ($document,$interpolate) {
        return {
            creatDialog:function (){
                //var div = angular.element("<div x-dialog-div></div>");
                var div = "<div x-dialog-div>{{name}}</div>";
                var interpolateDiv = $interpolate(div)({name:"wangyun"});
                $document.find("body").append(interpolateDiv);
            }
        };
    }]).
    directive('dialogDiv', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template:"<div>1111111111111111</div>",
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                console.log("123");
            }
        };
    }]);
```

myApp code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",["dialogApp"]).
        controller('conCtrl', ['$scope',"$document","dialogFactory", function ($scope,$document,dialogFactory) {

            $scope.creatDir = function (){
                //$document.find("body").append(div);
                dialogFactory.creatDialog();
            };
        }]);
```

How to trigger ***dialogApp***  of directive?
help me,thanks!

Comment: Did you mean the ***dialogDiv*** directive?

Comment: yes,How to trigger ___dialogApp___ directive?